# coin toss probabilities

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Flip 100 coins**

1. define a random variable that counts the number of heads
2. probability of getting exactly 5 heads
3. probability of getting at least 1 head
4. find the expected number of heads using the random variable defined above

---

So far I know there are $2^{100}$ possible outcomes, but I stuck from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probability of getting n heads = $\dfrac{\binom{100}{n}}{2^{100}}$
since the denominator expresses the number of ways you can get n heads and the denominator is all th epossible cases.

The probability of getting 5 heads then is $\dfrac{\binom{100}{5}}{2^{100}}$.

The probability of getting as least one head is the same as the probability of not getting 0 heads. This is $1-\dfrac{\binom{100}{1}}{2^{100}}=1-\dfrac{1}{2^{100}}$

Now to find the expected value we need to sum up the probability you get n heads multiplied by n. (so its gives you sort of like an average sum of heads after many experiments).

so this is $\sum_{n=0}^{100}\dfrac{\binom{100}{n}}{2^{100}}*n$